# Reload div only contact form 7 after sent

Tags: wordpress, redirect, contact-form-7

I was wondering if somebody can help me.
Contact form 7 is in a div ('contactform') and I want to reload this div only after a successful submission. Normally Contact form 7 redirects to ../#wpcf7-f44-o1 but I want to only 'reload' the div where the contact form is in.

Can someone help me with that? Or give me alternative(s)?

Many thanks.

Comment: The default CF7 functionality to simply submit via Ajax and show a success/error message...It should do what you're asking about, by default.

Comment: Yes, it shows the message but it reloads the entire page..